# Как скомпилировать файл .jar в .apk?

Tags: android, jar, apk

**Я декомпилировал программу для андроид и после некоторых манипуляций в jd-gui мне
надо скомпилировать обратно в .apk**

Comment: Ну... поскольку jd-gui в принципе не умеет редактировать код, то можете смело использовать оригинал;). Или идите на 4PDA - "плохому" учат там))).

Comment: Мне надо просто скомпилировать .jar обратно в .apk